# Show pictures insted of numbers in html?

Tags: html, asp-classic

In my asp web page, i want to show pictures instead of numbers.
For exampe, user enter 3467 in textbox in first page, on second page i want to show 3.jpg 4.jpg and etc. How can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't you use the Replace function.  Are your pictures images of numbers, in which case you could do something like

```
mynumber = Request.Form("mytextboxinput")
mynumber = Replace(mynumber, "0", "0.jpg")
mynumber = Replace(mynumber, "1", "1.jpg")
mynumber = Replace(mynumber, "2", "2.jpg")

etc
```

If your images are of something else and some of them have names like 10.jpg, 11.jpg then you would need to separate the numbers in your input, probably with commas, and do a bit of research into vbscript arrays

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Infact, i want the user to enter numbers on a page, after click button, page will show pictures which user entered instead of pictures. For example; user enter 317, page will show 3.jpg, 1.jpg and 7.jpg. I will use this on abacus app.